# DevExpress expressApp Framework Security System customize

Tags: c#, xaf

### **How do I use an existing database to implement RBAC in XAF Security System?**

I have added the Security Strategey Complex and Authentication Standard controls in the WinApplication.cs as the XAF tutorial told.

And my database has serval tables , a SysUser table which is equal to the user , a SysActor table which is equal to the role , and a SysActorRight table which is using describe the relationship between SysUser and SysActor.

And I have used the Persistent Classes Wizard  to generate XPO and make it inherited from SecuritySystemUser and SecuritySystemRoleBase.

But I couldn't set the Security Complex component's UserType and RoleType properties to my own types.
So what should I do ?

Thanks a lot for you reading my poor written-english.

Comment: I am not sure if you would be able to use your tables other than XAF required tables such as User without serious plumbing...refer to this doc "Custom Security System User Based on an Existing Business Class" http://documentation.devexpress.com/#Xaf/CustomDocument3384 and start from there.

Comment: I'm truly greatly for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are using `SecurityStrategyComplex` instead of `SecurityComplex`?
Are you sure `SysUser` implements `IUserWithRoles` and `SysActor` implements `IRole`?

There is a sample project showing a full implementation [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E1255).

For all DevExpress related questions, the first place to ask is the [Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/).

Comment: Your help was greatly appreciated.